# IF statement Error 9 (Subscript out of range)

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

In the code below I am getting a runtime error 9: Subscript out of range issue on the below marked line and I'm unable to determine the issue. Any ideas? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wsOPS As Worksheet
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim DeletedTL() As Integer
Dim ArraySize As Integer
Set wsOPS = wb.Worksheets.Add(Type:=xlWorksheet)

With wsOPS
    .Name = "OPS"
End With

LastRow = Sheets("OPS").UsedRange.Rows.Count
ArraySize = 0
For i = 1 To LastRow
    If wsOPS.Range("A" & i).FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = 0 Then '******Error here******
        ArraySize = ArraySize + 1
        DeletedTL = wsOPS.Range("C" & i)
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: My guess is that there aren't FormatConditions on all the cells in range A1:Ai ... you might want to check that wsOPS.Range("A" & i).FormatConditions.Count <> 0 before doing the IF ...

Comment: Not part of the problem, I think @TechnoDabbler got that, but `Sheet("OPS")` should be `wsOPS`.